# Pycharm refactoring-renaming inside function

Tags: refactoring, pycharm

In Pycharm one can easily rename a variable project wide using the (shift + F6) key to refactor-rename a variable

But it is unable to do this inside a function.

A workaround would be to use search-replace, But as I've gotten used to refactor-renaming i would like to find a way to refactor-rename inside a function.

[image]

Thanks for reading

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at and maybe answer this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980304/how-to-create-and-include-in-a-so-post-an-illustration-of-a-pycharm-sequence-of

Comment: The specific software used is http://licecap.en.softonic.com/

Comment: How do you pop up the dialogue menu? I only get the refactor menu when I right click the variable to be renamed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm recognizes the limited scope of the variable (inside the function) and refactoring behaves slightly different in this case - the usual refactoring dialogue no longer opens up.

The green background (in your example, the actual colour may differ depending on the color scheme and customisations) for all the variable's instances inside the function indicates pycharm is in this local refactoring mode. Just edit the variable name and you'll see all the variable instances being modified simultaneously. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when done and the green background disappears indicating that the local refactoring mode ended.

Comment: How do you pop up the dialogue menu? I only get the refactor menu when I right click the variable to be renamed?

Comment: @PedroMartinez right-click is the only way AFAIK, but I usually just Shift-F6 and refactor without the menu