# How to create and include in a SO post an illustration of a pycharm sequence of operations?

Tags: gif, animated-gif

I stumbled over this SO post containing a very useful illustration of a sequence of [Pycharm operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39976747/4794).

[image: Screencast]

How can such illustration can be captured and inserted in an SO post?

Comment: That's simply an animated GIF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Animated_GIF

Comment: I gathered as much, the question is how to obtain the gif from pycharm.

Comment: if you are on mac try giphy capture

Comment: The specific software used is http://licecap.en.softonic.com/

Comment: Ah, I thought it's a PyCharm feature I didn't discover yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @a_horse_with_no_name commented, it is an animated GIF. You can use a screencast software to record a short demo / tutorial and save it to an animated GIF.

Some screencast software like Recordit would work.
http://recordit.co/